# How do I edit the contribution confirmation page

Tags: contributions

How do I edit the contribution confirmation page? I need to change the text so that the instructions are consistent with the buttons

[image]

Comment: This is being updated in core (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1407) so should be available in a future release.

Comment: So it can't be changed?

Comment: @Kirsten the solution Mick suggests below is available now.  What's going to change is that the default text of the "Confirm" button will change to "Confirm Your Contribution" to make it easier to target the button text itself as part of word replacement.  However, you're correct that the language should be consistent out of the box, which is what issue #1407 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably manage it with Adminster >> Customise Data and Screens >> Word Replacements if you chose a sufficiently long phrase to ensure it doesn't affect anything elsewhere.